# TFS doesn't publish ANT test results from a relative path

Tags: ant, tfs, junit, continuous-integration

I have created an ANT build for an eclipse project and its associated unit tests using Team Foundation Server 2010. However I am having trouble getting it to publish the results of the unit tests to TFS.

The build.xml file itself seems to function correctly in that it builds the project and creates an xml results file. The issue seems to be within the TFSBuild.proj and the publishing of the test results to TFS.

Using the following code, the build executes successfully and publishes the results to TFS as I would expect:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AntBuildFile Include="$(SolutionRoot)/StockMoves/build.xml">
    <Targets></Targets>
    <Properties>BinariesRoot=$(BinariesRoot);BuildDefinitionName=$(BuildDefinitionName);BuildDefinitionUri=$(BuildDefinitionUri);BuildDirectory=$(BuildDirectory);BuildNumber=$(BuildNumber);DropLocation=$(DropLocation);LogLocation=$(LogLocation);SourceGetVersion=$(SourceGetVersion);TestResultsRoot=$(TestResultsRoot);TeamProject=$(TeamProject);WorkspaceName=$(WorkspaceName);WorkspaceOwner=$(WorkspaceOwner)</Properties>
    <Lib></Lib>
  </AntBuildFile>

  <JUnitLogFiles Include="$(SolutionRoot)/StockMoves/test/TEST-unittest.TestSuite.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, when attempting to change the path in which JUnit looks to this:

```
<JUnitLogFiles Include="$(SolutionRoot)/**/TEST-*.TestSuite.xml" />
```

Then the test results are no longer published. I know this formatting works as I've successfully used it in other builds but this one has me stumped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I've solved this!

It would seem that for whatever reason, that the file in question must already exist when the build is run. I added an empty xml file with the same name as the file produced by my test results and now the results are published to TFS.